# Why Is my C# object not instantiating?

Tags: c#, oop

Why is this Application object NOT instantiating? It is null whenever I run the code.

```
public class Applicant
{
    private Application oApplication = new Application();

    public Applicant()
    { 
        oApplication = new Application();
    }

    public Application Application
    {
        get { return oApplication; }
        set { oApplication = value; }
    }             
}
```

Here is the Application Class

```
    public class Application
{
    public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public ContactDetails ContactDetails { get; set; }   
}
```

And here is the calling code....

```
        public Applicant[] GetApplicants()
    {
        Applicant[] oApplicant;

        DataSet dsExcelSchema = new DataSet();
        dsExcelSchema = GetDataAsDataSet();

        DataTable contactInfoTable = dsExcelSchema.Tables["ContactInformation$"];
        int numOfApplications = contactInfoTable.Rows.Count - 1;
        int i = 0;

        oApplicant = new Applicant[numOfApplications];

        foreach (DataRow dr in contactInfoTable.Rows)
        {
            Application oApplication = new Application();

            oApplicant[i].Application.ApplicationID = dr["ApplicationID"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        return oApplicant;
    }
```

It give me a a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Going to need the code you're using to perform said call to say for sure

Comment: How does the code look like that runs this code?

Comment: How have you concluded this?

Comment: how do you check it is `null`, how do you use `Applicant` class? you can delete constructor, btw.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Are you perhaps swallowing the exceptions? Post the `Application` class.

Comment: Some other code setting Application to null i.e. appObject.Application = Null

Comment: Apl = new Applicant();
Apl.Application == null ???

Comment: Where is the `Application` class? If you use `System.Windows.Forms.Application` then there is no accessible constructor.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but is it OK to have a type and a property with the same name?

Comment: `public Application Application` this is baaaaaad

Comment: @Thomas: it's absolutely fine to use a type-name for the property-name. Consider you've implemented a custom control which has a `Color` property that returns it's `Color`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter *I* don't like it. And I'm sure I'm not the only one. But you're right, maybe my comment was a little bit *useless*

Comment: @TimSchmelter then you'll see some guys trying to do `public int int{get;set;}` and wonder why it doesn't work

Comment: `public int @int { get; set; }` works. Even though, I wouldn't give my properties such meaningless names.

Comment: @Thomas: i don't see why you would  need a property with a name `int`. That's an alias for a very specific type. It's also a [keywod in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), so you can't use it as property name(for what it's worth, you could use `public int  @int { get; set; } ` or `public Int32 Int32 { get; set; } `).

Comment: On the other side, I actually enjoy using same name for classes and variables/properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgot to create instance of applicant in array element - should be done like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in contactInfoTable.Rows)
{
    oApplicant[i] = new Applicant();
    oApplicant[i].Application.ApplicationID = dr["ApplicationID"].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Switching from VB to C# and got led down the wrong trail on that one.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an array of objects:

```
oApplicant = new Applicant[numOfApplications];
```

It will be filled with `nulls`. So you need to initialize it with real values at first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfApplications; i++)
{
    oApplicant[i] = new Applicant();
}
```

Comment: `null` is *real* value

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman `null` means no value.  That could be seen as not a real value.  Though "instances of the class" would be more precise than "real values" here.

Comment: `null` is a pointer constant to a forbidden region. In most implementations, if not all, the adress value of `null` is in fact zero - and that's a *real* value.
Despite that, a variable of a reference type with the value set to `null` is commonly interpreted as if the variable "has no associated value".

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman you are talking about what `null` **technically** is, but semantically it is just nothing.

Comment: Of course I am talking in technical terms - what did you expect here?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I don't understand the point of your comment. `null` is nothing semantically, no real value as @juharr said.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other answers, you also need to set the numOfApplications to contactInfoTable.Rows.Count, and not contactInfoTable.Rows.Count - 1;

int numOfApplications = contactInfoTable.Rows.Count;